# Wordpress Mysql wpdb query duplicates despite using DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I've already looked at all similar solved questions but I've not found the solution yet.

So In this wordpress there are houses and circuits (custom post types). A house can have several circuits attached (repeater custom field ). The query gets dinamically built to retrieve all houses associated to *any* circuit from a list of IDS.

This works, but it repeats a house when it has more than one circuit that matches. For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM reoask5_posts p 
INNER JOIN reoask5_postmeta pm_ci ON p.ID = pm_ci.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'casa'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND pm_ci.meta_key LIKE 'circuito|__|_ci' ESCAPE '|'
AND (pm_ci.meta_value = 194 OR pm_ci.meta_value = 189)
```

...retrieves houseA which has circuito_0_ci = 194 and retrieves **two times** houseB which has circuito_0_ci = 194 and circuito_1_ci = 189 associated.

So what should I modify to filter out duplicates? What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE1:** More info

[The table schema for posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_posts) (p)
[The table schema for postmeta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_postmeta) (pm_ci)

Still doesn't work well. Selectin specific columns from post database does filter out duplicates. But it fails in looping through the results like a normal wordpress loop. Even if I select ALL the columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.post_author, p.post_date, p.post_date_gmt, p.post_content, p.post_title, p.post_excerpt, p.post_status, p.comment_status, p.ping_status, p.post_password, p.post_name, p.to_ping, p.pinged, p.post_modified, p.post_modified_gmt, p.post_content_filtered, p.post_parent, p.guid, p.menu_order, p.post_type, p.post_mime_type, p.comment_count
```

It gives me errors:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ID in .... line 250
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ID in .... line 251
// etc...
```

This the simplified php code that comes after defining the query. All of these calls fail when I select specific columns:

```
$total_posts= $wpdb->get_results($query);

foreach ($total_posts as $post){
    $post->post_name;
    get_permalink($post->ID);
    $coordenadas = get_field( "coords", $post->ID);

    // ...
}
```

If I add all the 4 columns from metaposts to the SELECT line:

```
... p.comment_count, pm_ci.meta_id, pm_ci.post_id, pm_ci.meta_key, pm_ci.meta_value
```

It still gives me errors when trying to use those functions, that work when I use `SELECT *`

And I don't know how would I be supposed to use group by in this case. Still learning.

**UPDATE2:** Found the solution

The reason for the errors was because `SELECT DISTINCT p.id` should read `SELECT DISTINCT p.ID` . The SQL query returned the ID in a case insensitive manner, storing it in key 'id' , but the wordpress functions need that key in capitals ('ID') in order to work.

Thank you!

Comment: You should give the table schema and some sample data to be easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using  `DISTINCT *` . This means that if one value in any one column is different (from a different row) it will be shown.

What you should instead do, is write distinct followed by the specific columns your interested in.

So, if your only interested in the specific houses -

***Example:***

```
select distinct houses
FROM ...
```

***Using your Format:***

```
select distinct
p.post_type
    FROM ...
```

You could also use `GROUP BY` to count the number of different circuits a house has.

Comment: Thanks this is a start. But still havent found the solution. I've updated the question.

Comment: Solved. I've marked yours as the answer because it pointed me in the right direction. Thank you.